# How to transfer queries via http if the Receiver can handle only SQLStatements or Expressions

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-cosmosdb

I started recently to use CosmosDB with the Core (SQL) API to use CosmosDB as DocumentDB. But the Interface of CosmosDB, primarily CosmosDBClient.CreateDocumentQuery() [1] and .CreateDatabaseQuery() [2] accepts only Expression or SQL statements. Now I am stuck because the query gets in as a string but has to be translated somehow and I am afraid that whatever I try will never be good enough to be considered as stable.

- The question would be now how to handle the query that comes from a web interface and should be used from an internal sqlstatement/expression interface?

If you ask why the query is getting in as a string: We use microservices which are triggered via (e.g.:) HTTP GET. And with this GET a query should be provided, for example as Parameter ...?name=Hans&surname=Wurst Or even ODATA.

**Links:**

- [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet
- [2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdatabasequery?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Where you can use the SQL API with a client library to create a document (See [DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet)) and create a database (See [DocumentClient.CreateDatabaseQuery Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdatabasequery?view=azure-dotnet)), there is a corresponding REST API to make that same call and will return items in a JSON string:

[REST: Create Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document)

[REST: Create Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-database)

As an option.

Comment: I've looked into how to query documents via REST from CosmosDB. The Query has to be a SQLStatement, so this doesn't solve the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api